# IE11 : script70 permission denied when accessing element from another iframe

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, iframe

My application has 2 iframes, a main-iframe from which the user selects a file  and a side-iframe which gets the file from the main-iframe, slices it and uploads it slice-by-slice to the server using XMLHttpRequest and AJAX.

The main-iframe can be navigated and present many different pages, so as I navigate away from the upload page I get a script70 : permission denied in IE11 as the file.slice() function is being called.

This works fine in Chrone and FireFox, as I can navigate through different pages while the side-iframe continues to slice the file and upload it via AJAX.

To be more specific, the code in the side-iframe looks a bit like this :

```
var file_select = top.frames['mainFrame'].document.getElementById('fileSelect').
var the_file = file_select.files[0];
the_file.slice();
```

Any solutions?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest and AJAX are the same thing. Post some sample code.

Comment: Added code above.